# How to show document preview in iCloud conflicts sheet in Mac App using NSDocument

Tags: conflict, icloud, nsdocument

I am creating a Mac App, using NSDocument, that stores a custom class of documents to iCloud.

I was able to get the program to store documents to iCloud quite easily by just Code Signing it, Sandboxing it, and adding iCloud entitlements; however, I'm still encountering a problem where when I trigger an iCloud conflict and the program drops down the sheet allowing the user to resolve the conflict the rows in the sheet do not show the small image of the document (like Preview and TextEdit do).

Additionally, when I click on the area where the image should be (it's blank) it opens up a Quick Look window that just displays an image of the Document Icon together with some other information as opposed to a snap shot of the actual file like Preview and TextEdit do.

I have not found any information in Apple's documentation that explains what I need to do to implement the same behaviour as Preview and TextEdit.

So far I've been surprised by how easily I've been able to get all of the functionability of not only the Auto Saves and the Versions browser, but also saving to the Cloud. NSDocument seems to do all of this for the developer (resolving iCloud Conflicts, etc.), as Apple's documents says it does, but again I'm not getting this other behaviour and I don't want to reinvent the wheel by writing code that is not needed.

I'm thinking that the answer might lie somewhere with implementing a Quick Look thumbnail (for the small image in the table in the sheet) and a Quick Look preview for the larger preview of the document when that in the sheet is clicked on, but this seems like a lot of work and I'm afraid of losing some of the other build-in functions of NSDocument if I start "trapping" NSDocument routines up the food chain so to speak.

Has anyone else encountered this problem and found the easiest solution?

Update: Dec. 25/12

I've finally figured out that the problem is I need a QuickLook generator to display both a QL Thumbnail (which shows up in the table in the conflicts sheet) and a QL Preview (which is displayed when a user clicks on the Thumbnail)

I ended up creating the QL generator project, and afterwards creating a workspace which I added my main project and the QL generator project to. After that I added a Copy Files Build Phase to the main project to copy the QL generator into the main Application bundle.